# Security of vagrant boxes - who maintains them?

Tags: vagrant

Is there anywhere to see who a box is maintained by?

For example the `debian` related boxes at https://app.vagrantup.com/debian - are these official images/boxes maintained by "The Debian Project"?

What functionality is in place to ensure boxes do not have malware etc in them?